# Add Link Reference in Excel using OneDrive

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, onedrive, hyperlink

I have two workbooks, and I am trying to link the two files in Excel O365 in OneDrive.

I have had limited success doing the following command on my PC or directly on OneDrive. Placing this command in my destination file seems to work, but I want to use a variable for the `ABBV` file description name.

I have a long list of files that I want to pull data from by changing these four characters in the filename.

```
='https://d.docs.live.net/a232a8d5885c0/Documents/Investing/Portfolio Management/EMB_JBB/Active Binder Financial Plan/[03_EMB JBB STOCK ANALYSIS_ONE PAGER - WiseCharts.xlsx]ABBV'!$J$24
```

However, I want to use a variable in the place of the `ABBV` in the string. I have tried several alternatives shown below and cannot get it to work.

Option A:

```
="'https://d.docs.live.net/a232a8d5885c0/Documents/Investing/Portfolio Management/EMB_JBB/Active Binder Financial Plan/[03_EMB JBB STOCK ANALYSIS_ONE PAGER - WiseCharts.xlsx]" & "ABBV" & "'!$J$24"
```

Option B:

```
=Concatentate("'https://d.docs.live.net/a232a8d5885c0/Documents/Investing/Portfolio Management/EMB_JBB/Active Binder Financial Plan/[03_EMB JBB STOCK ANALYSIS_ONE PAGER - WiseCharts.xlsx]" & "ABBV" & "'!$J$24")
```

Option C:

```
=indirect("'https://d.docs.live.net/a232a8d5885c0/Documents/Investing/Portfolio Management/EMB_JBB/Active Binder Financial Plan/[03_EMB JBB STOCK ANALYSIS_ONE PAGER - WiseCharts.xlsx]" & "ABBV" & "'!$J$24")
```

Option D:

```
=indirect(Concatenate("'https://d.docs.live.net/a232a8d5885c0/Documents/Investing/Portfolio Management/EMB_JBB/Active Binder Financial Plan/[03_EMB JBB STOCK ANALYSIS_ONE PAGER - WiseCharts.xlsx]" & "ABBV" & "'!$J$24"))
```

Does anybody have a solution on how to get this to work so I can use a variable for `ABBV`?

Here is more detail....
Thank you for your comment MGonet. Here is a slice of the destination file. Note my replacements for ABBV are in Column A and the links will go into every cell D through M for 40 rows.  So ultimately I will have to set up some type of a loop for each column to find the linked data for each spreadsheet in the target folder folder. The data is produced in the target folder with 40 sheets. What I am doing is looking at a subset of the data in the 40 sheets for a comparison of key metrics (i.e. ROIC, Profit Margin, etc.). Each stock listed in column A corresponds with a tab (spreadsheet) in the target file. The destination file will have to loop through each metric for a given tab (e.g. ABBV). Each piece of data is located within the tab at a different location. Does this help you understand the problem better? I think I need a loop for each row A6:A46 and D through M for each row loop that changes the value of "ABBV" and then cell location D thorugh M. . Row D woud be cell "O15"; Row E cell would be "O14"; Row F cell would be "J24"; Row G would be "J23"; Row H would be "J13";  Row I would be "I19"; Row J would be "I18"; Row K would be "J32"; L would be "J30"; M would be "J35". [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJEya.png)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write how exactly you want to change this name. From the formula presented, it appears that it is the name of the sheet (I assume always 4 letters), placed after the parenthesis `]`. To change it, you need VBA code, for example in the `Change` event handler.
Let's assume this scenario: your formula is in cell `A3`. In cell `F3`, we create a drop-down list with all variants of variable fragments of type `ABBV`. In the `Change` event handler, this will be the `Target` cell.
In the code module of the worksheet in which these cells are located, we define a handler for the `Change` event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$F$3" Then
        Dim f As String, wkn As String
        f = Range("A3").Formula
        wkn = Mid(f, InStr(f, "]") + 1, 4)
        Range("A3").Formula = Replace(f, wkn, Target.Value)
    End If
End Sub
```

By changing cell `F3` (i.e. by selecting a variable fragment), we insert this fragment into the formula in cell `A3` always in the same place (4 characters after the bracket `]`).
Of course, you can adjust the way you use this idea to your needs.